# Reference an Item Added to Class Library Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, class-library

I have a question that I can't seem to find the answer too, which probably means I'm searching wrong.

I am creating a C# library and I'm trying to reference a file I added. In this case, I'm using a simple text document to test.  I've added the text file, but I can't seem to find how to manipulate it reference it in my code.  I've got the file set to be an embedded resource if that makes any difference.  I'm sure it's something simple (assuming it's even possible), but it's just not clicking with me.

Comment: You don't really need to add a reference to a text file in order to read from it. Just open it and read.. [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ahhh, so it is literally that simple?  I didn't realize all you had to do was add the file name and .NET would infer same directory.  I'm going to test that out, thank you.

Comment: [There is the way to access embedded resource](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/319292?wa=wsignin1.0). But i think this is not what you looking for

Comment: @BBLAdmin Yes - there's no need to hard-code a reference to your text file into the c# project. In the MSDN example, they only provide a filename for the input string, but that could also be the full path to the file, known only at runtime.

Comment: I am getting a "value cannot be null" error when running this.  I have checked and I do have content in the text file, and the textfile name I'm referencing is definitely correct too.